# Quiero conocer la linea de comando Batch para eliminar archivos de múltiples carpetas a la vez

Tags: cmd, batch

Acudo aquí hoy porque quiero conocer el código para eliminar todos los archivos de múltiples carpetas pero con un solo archivo bat, intente con el siguiente linea de comando el cual  solo borro el de la primera carpeta las demás quedaron con todos los archivos.

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba
del /f /q /S *.*
cd C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba2
del /f /q /S *.*
cd C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba3
del /f /q /S *.*
exit
```

Comment: Saludos. Mira el comando `deltree` *(desde luego esto en ambiente windows)*.

Comment: Me puede guiar? soy un principiante en esto.

Comment: Puedes utilizar `del /s "H:\New Folder\Probar1", "H:\New Folder\Probar2"` si deseas eliminar todos los archivos (no los directorios) de los directorios que separas por comas, pero tendrás que confirmar si deseas eliminarlos o no (pregunta por cada uno de los archivos). Si deseas hacer lo explicado anteriormente, pero sin la pregunta de confirmación: `del /s /q "H:\New Folder\Probar1", "H:\New Folder\Probar2"`. Eso sí, esto es asumiendo que desees eliminar todos los archivos de los directorios especificados y de todos sus subdirectorios.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. @BodyBoard revise un poco, y para windows 10 el comando `deltree` que te mencione es ahora `rd`; puedes obtener ayuda del mismo colocando `rd /?` así se mostrara las opciones de que dispone (cualquier comando de windows tiene esa opción). Saludos en particular el `rd` veo solo tiene 2 opciones; te será fácil.

Comment: Además, si agregas `/f`, te permitirá forzar la eliminación de archivos de sólo lectura: `del /s /f /q "H:\New Folder\Probar1", "H:\New Folder\Probar2"`

Comment: Me di cuenta que solo necesitaba borrar una,  lo quiero usar para borrar los archivos de la carpeta roaming de los archivos temporales pero ahora se me presento problema, el cmd lo quería para limpiar los archivos de las computadoras en mi cyber café sin tener que estar abriendo algún software para limpiarlos, el problemas esta  que las maquinas tienen diferente nombres de usuarios hay alguna forma estandar de ubicar la carpeta especifica sin importar los nombres de usuarios? Y muchas gracias por tus respuestas amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Para eliminar carpetas y su contenido, incluyendo subcarpetas, puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
RMDIR /Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba
```

Donde

`/Q`: modo silencioso, no solicitará confirmación para eliminar carpetas.

`/S`: ejecuta la operación en todas las carpetas de la ruta seleccionada.

por lo tanto puedes usar para eliminar multiples carpetas y todo su contenido:

```
@echo off
RMDIR /Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba
RMDIR /Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba2
RMDIR /Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba3
exit
```

---

Si deseas eliminar únicamente los archivos y mantener las carpetas y subcarpetas usa:

```
@echo off
DEL /F/Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba > NUL
DEL /F/Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba2 > NUL
DEL /F/Q/S C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Prueba3 > NUL
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta tu último comentario, el cuadro de lo que quieres hacer queda más claro.

Accede a la carpeta `AppData\Roaming` del usuario

```
cd %APPDATA%
```

Elimina todos los archivos temporales del directorio y subdirectorios

```
del /F /S *.tmp
```